# IllegalStateException:switcher.setText

Tags: java, android, android-studio, exception, layout

```
          java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
              at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
           Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
              at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
              at android.widget.TextSwitcher.setText(TextSwitcher.java:78)
              at com.example.admin_u5214628.magiceight.MainActivity.answer(MainActivity.java:27)
```

The line 27 is:`switcher.setText(message);`

```
package com.example.admin_u5214628.magiceight;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextSwitcher;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Random r = new Random();
    static final String messages[] = {"Yes", "I would think so", "It is so", "No", "Not a chance", "Never",  "maybe", "I would rather not say"};
    TextSwitcher switcher;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        switcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.textSwitcher);
    }

    void answer(View v) {
        String message = messages[r.nextInt(messages.length)];

        switcher.setText(message);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add TextView as child, or even better, factory

```
        textSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {
        @Override
        public View makeView() {
            TextView switcherTextView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            switcherTextView.setTextSize(24);
            switcherTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            return switcherTextView;
        }
    });
```

and then you can set text to TextSwitcher.